# Constructor injection not work with qualifiers in @Statless bean

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c, java-ee-7

I encountered the next exciting problem. If I try to run the next code on Weblogic 12.2.1.3.0:

---

```
package hu.sample.bean;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.util.Random;

@Slf4j
@Stateless
public class Salutatory {

    private Butler butler;
    private Butler assistant;

    public Salutatory() {}

    @Inject
    public Salutatory(@MainButler Butler mainButler,
                      @Assistant Butler assistant) {
        this.butler = mainButler;
        this.assistant = assistant;
        log.debug("Call with {} {}", mainButler, assistant);
    }

    public String salute(String name) {
        if (new Random().nextBoolean()) {
            return butler.welcome(name + "1");
        } else  {
            return assistant.welcome(name + "2");
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
package hu.sample.bean;

public interface Butler {

    String welcome(String name);
}
```

---

```
package hu.sample.bean;

import javax.inject.Qualifier;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.*;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER})
public @interface MainButler {
}
```

---

```
package hu.sample.bean;

import javax.inject.Qualifier;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.*;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER})
public @interface Assistant {
}
```

---

```
package hu.sample.bean;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Alternative;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Any;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Stateless
@MainButler
public class George implements Butler {

    @Override
    public String welcome(String name) {
        return String.format("Hello, I'm Geroge, I'm the main butler. Welcom here %s! (%s)", name, this.getClass());
    }
}
```

---

```
package hu.sample.bean;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
@Assistant
public class Peter implements Butler {

    @Override
    public String welcome(String name) {
        return String.format("Hello, I'm Peter, I'm an assistant. Welcom here %s! (%s)", name, this.getClass());
    }
}
```

I get the next exception.:

```
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Butler with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] public hu.sample.bean.Salutatory_mv77ws_Impl(Butler, Butler)
  at hu.sample.bean.Salutatory_mv77ws_Impl.<init>(Salutatory_mv77ws_Impl.java:0)
WELD-001475: The following beans match by type, but none have matching qualifiers:
  - Session bean [class hu.sample.bean.Peter with qualifiers [@Assistant @Any]; local interfaces are [Butler],
  - Session bean [class hu.sample.bean.George with qualifiers [@MainButler @Any]; local interfaces are [Butler]
```

Ok, I understand this and I create a default implementation of Butler. But in this case the CDI injects default implementation every time, ignored the qualifiers. Why?

The qualifiers works well, if I use setter injection, field injection, etc...

If Salutatory is @WebServlet the constructor injection with qualifiers also works well.

But, why don't constructor injection with qualifiers works well in @Stateless bean?

Many thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

To inject an EJB it's best to use the `javax.ejb.EJB` annotation in an EJB injection context. (i.e. the injection point is an EJB itself)

In this case, you can use the simple name of the class as the `beanName` to choose which implementation to inject.

In your case, instead of qualifying the beans in the constructor, do so for each field.

```java
    @EJB(beanName="George")
    private Butler butler;

    @EJB(beanName="Peter")
    private Butler assistant;
```